# I have a problem when compiling AOSP with Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, makefile, open-source, android-source

```
klee@linux:~/AOSP/aosp$ make
......

[  0% 2/12593] build out/target/produc...wer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex
FAILED: out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex 
/bin/bash -c "(mkdir -p out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/ && rm -f out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex ) && (find out/target/common/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/ -maxdepth 1 -name \"classes*.dex\" | sort | xargs zip -qjX out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex ) && (mv out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex.input ) && (rm -f out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex ) && (mkdir -p out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/ ) && (ANDROID_LOG_TAGS=\"*:e\" out/host/linux-x86/bin/dex2oatd --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --class-loader-context=\"&\" --boot-image=out/target/product/generic/dex_bootjars/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex.input --dex-location=/system/app/HTMLViewer/HTMLViewer.apk --oat-file=out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex --android-root=out/target/product/generic/system --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xnorelocate --compile-pic --no-generate-debug-info --generate-build-id --abort-on-hard-verifier-error --force-determinism --no-inline-from=core-oj.jar  --compiler-filter=quicken ) && (rm out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex.input )"
dex2oatd F 10-23 16:22:30  2859  2859 utils.cc:762] ANDROID_DATA not set and /data does not exist
Runtime aborting...
Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock mutator lock
All threads:
DALVIK THREADS (0):
"dex2oatd" prio=5 (not attached)
  | sysTid=2859 nice=0 cgrp=default
  | state=R schedstat=( 20700891 0 180 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=2 HZ=100
  native: #00 pc 00000000004f55f9  /home/klee/AOSP/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+217)
  native:   art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)
  native:    art/runtime/native_stack_dump.cc:300
  native: #01 pc 00000000005eda90  /home/klee/AOSP/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd.so (art::ThreadList::DumpUnattachedThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+352)
  native:   art::DumpUnattachedThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, bool)
  native:    art/runtime/thread_list.cc:166
  native:   art::ThreadList::DumpUnattachedThreads(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)
  native:    art/runtime/thread_list.cc:189
  native: #02 pc 00000000005ed860  /home/klee/AOSP/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/lib64/libartd.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+288)
  native:   art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)

......

"dex2oat watch d" prio=5 (not attached)
  | sysTid=2860 nice=0 cgrp=default
  | state=S schedstat=( 30164 0 1 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0 HZ=100
  kernel: (couldn't read /proc/self/task/2860/stack)
  native: #00 pc 0000000000069117  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (???)
  native: #01 pc 000000000006be9a  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (pthread_cond_timedwait+570)
  native:   __vfwscanf_internal
  native:    ./stdio-common/vfscanf-internal.c:1733
  native: #02 pc 000000000001612d  /home/klee/AOSP/aosp/out/host/linux-x86/bin/dex2oatd (art::WatchDog::Wait()+109)

.......

/bin/bash: line 1:  2859 Aborted                 (core dumped) ( ANDROID_LOG_TAGS="*:e" out/host/linux-x86/bin/dex2oatd --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --class-loader-context="&" --boot-image=out/target/product/generic/dex_bootjars/system/framework/boot.art --dex-file=out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex.input --dex-location=/system/app/HTMLViewer/HTMLViewer.apk --oat-file=out/target/product/generic/obj/APPS/HTMLViewer_intermediates/oat/arm/package.odex --android-root=out/target/product/generic/system --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-variant=generic --instruction-set-features=default --runtime-arg -Xnorelocate --compile-pic --no-generate-debug-info --generate-build-id --abort-on-hard-verifier-error --force-determinism --no-inline-from=core-oj.jar --compiler-filter=quicken )
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
16:22:42 ninja failed with: exit status 1
make: *** [build/core/main.mk:21: run_soong_ui] Error 1
klee@linux:~/AOSP/aosp$
```

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Please help me, I haven't found a solution to this problem on the internet

I don't know what's going on, if anyone knows how to fix this please help me, it's crazy and I've been spending days on it

[Complete error message image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJCg2.png)

[Complete error message image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PToeb.png)

[Complete error message image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dufEW.png)

[Complete error message image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WrOWz.png)

Comment: It may be that the compiled Android version is too low. I also have this problem when compiling Android 8.0 using 22.04. Both virtual machines and physical machines have this problem. But it can be compiled with WSL 22.04, which feels a bit strange. I'm going to use Ubuntu 18.04 to compile Android 8.0 to see if it works.